# TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable

Tags: python, glob

I am trying to recursively iterate through folders to assign a particular file to a variable for later parsing, however I am receiving the following error:

```py
TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable
```

```py
Flask version 1.0.2 (not sure if its relevant)
Python version 3.7.3
```

Imports:

```
from pathlib import Path
from glob import glob
```

Code:

```
def parse_info(bundle_path):
    file_list = []
    for filename in Path(bundle_path).glob('**/*.*'):
        file_list.append(filename)

    for elem in file_list:
        if 'uname' in elem:
            print('present')
```

Call:

```
parse_info(<some path>)
```

The `'print(filename)'` does print out all the files in that path and the desired search string is present in that print output, so I know it exists, however just not sure how to capture that element for later. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

The answer in this case was to cast the filename to a string when appending it to the list:

```
file_list.append(str(filename))
```

Answer (score 2):

For others, who are getting the same error(using Pathlib). There's a possibility that you might have forgotten the syntax to iterate through the dictionary. The syntax is:

```
for key, value in _dict.items():
    print(f"key: {key} value: {value}")
```

Notice the `.items()`; I was using `.values()` method, silly mistake.
It's not an answer but just a headsup to save others time.