# TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterabl

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations, django-manage.py

please help i get this error from python manage.py makemigrations

> Migrations for 'post':   post/migrations/0022_auto_20200929_1749.py
> - Remove field category from post
> - Remove field tag from post Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 22, in 
> main()   File "manage.py", line 18, in main
> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
> line 381, in execute_from_command_line
> utility.execute()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
> line 375, in execute
> self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 336, in run_from_argv
> connections.close_all()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 224, in
> close_all
> connection.close()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py",
> line 248, in close
> if not self.is_in_memory_db():   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py",
> line 367, in is_in_memory_db
> return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])   File
> "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/creation.py",
> line 12, in is_in_memory_db
> return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterabl

models.py
from django.db import models

```
> # Create your models here. from django.db import models from django.utils import timezone
> 
> 
> class Post(models.Model):
>     author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE ,null=True)
>     title = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
>     description=models.TextField(default='a')
>     text = models.TextField(null=True)
>     Img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',null =True)
>     UserImg= models.ImageField(upload_to='images/user/',null =True)
> 
>     created_date = models.DateTimeField(
>             default=timezone.now)
>     published_date = models.DateTimeField(
>             blank=True, null=True)
> 
>     def publish(self):
>         self.published_date = timezone.now()
>         self.save()
> 
>     def __str__(self):
>         return self.title
>     def approved_comments(self):
>      return self.comments.filter(approved_comment=True)
> 
> class Comment(models.Model):
>     post = models.ForeignKey('post.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
>     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
>     text = models.TextField()
>     email=models.EmailField(null=True)
>     created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
>     approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)
> 
>     def approve(self):
>         self.approved_comment = True
>         self.save()
> 
>     def __str__(self):
>         return self.text
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57024338/typeerror-argument-of-type-posixpath-is-not-iterable

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: @seagull13 does my answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is somewhat misrepresented, telling it to delete a `field` that doesn't exist(or may have existed before) but shouldn't be the cause of the error when making migrations.

> Migrations for 'post': post/migrations/0022_auto_20200929_1749.py - Remove field category from post - Remove field tag from post Traceback

If I am correct, you may be using `Django 3.1`, which moved the BASE_DIR pseudo-setting to use `pathlib.Path` rather than a plain string. Support for this needed adding `str()` to some places like the sqlite driver.

If you look at the definition of BASE_DIR in your settings file, is it using a Path() ? If so you can use str() around its use in your DATABASES setting, i.e. `str(BASE_DIR / "something.sqlite")`.

Read here for more -  [Use Pathlib in Your Django Settings File](https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/03/16/use-pathlib-in-your-django-project/)